# Jquery datatables - How count numbers of rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using to Jquery [datables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) to create a table with [row details](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) . Everything working fine Only the number of entries
[image]

The current logic is counting the parents row + child rows. I want to count only parents rows which are 4. My result should be **Showing 1 to 10 of 4 entries**.

In my Json file, I have `recordsTotal: 16` which is the total rows parents + child. When I change to 4 which is number of parents rows the table will show me only first record (Ticket id 1 + its 3 child rows ) as it's counted as 4 entries.

Any suggestions please how can I update ? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function format ( d ) {  

d.Items.sort(function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.Line_No < b.Line_No)
    return -1;
  if (a.Line_No > b.Line_No)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}); 

   var x = '<table class="nowrap table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Line No</th><th>Line Level Issue</th><th>Created Date</th><th>Created By</th></tr></thead><tbody>' ;
     
$.each(d.Items, function( index, value ) {
  x += '<tr><td>' + d.Items[index].Line_No + '</td><td>' + d.Items[index].Line_Level_Issue + '</td><td>' + d.Items[index].Created_Date + '</td><td>' + d.Items[index].Created_By + '</td></tr>';
});

        x +='</tbody></table>';
        return x; 
}

    var dt = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "language": { "emptyTable": "No matching records found",
        "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
        "zeroRecords": "No matching records found" },
        "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/vwjfc", 
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          "details-control",
                "data":           "Ticket_id"
                ,render : function(data, type, row) {
              return '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;' + data;
          }
            },
            { "data": "Order_Level_Issue" },
            { "data": "Geo" },
            { "data": "Region" },
            { "data": "Territory" },
            { "data": "Market" },
            { "data": "Country" },
            { "data": "SoldTo_Number" },
            { "data": "SoldTo_Name" },
            { "data": "Order_Numer" }

        ],
        "order": [[0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']]
    } );
 
    var detailRows = [];
 
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = dt.row( tr );
        var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            tr.removeClass( 'details' );
            row.child.hide();

            detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
        }
        else {
            tr.addClass( 'details' );
            row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

            if ( idx === -1 ) {
                detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
            }
        }
    } );
 
    dt.on( 'draw', function () {
        $.each( detailRows, function ( i, id ) {
            $('#'+id+' td.details-control').trigger( 'click' );
        } );
    } );




} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.details td.details-control {
    background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<table id="example" class="nowrap table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>TicketT id</th>
                <th>Order Level Issue</th>
                <th>Geo</th>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>SoldTo Number</th>
                <th>SoldTo Name</th>
                <th>Order Numer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Ticket id</th>
                <th>Order Level Issue</th>
                <th>Geo</th>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>SoldTo Number</th>
                <th>SoldTo Name</th>
                <th>Order Numer</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"Showing 1 to 10 of 4"* - are you sure??  Doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @freedomn-m  i will update the text after, it should be 'showing 4 tickets'

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem was not dataTables at all but your ajax call, since you are using **serverSide** your server side is the one who sends the data the table will display including the total of records so in your ajax response you have:

`{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 16, recordsFiltered: 16, data: Array(4)}`

So all you have to do is work in your server side script in order the reflect the expected output.

Hope it helps